# Fetch multiple onetoMany relationships Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

I am using Hibernate JPA 1.0.

I have the following type of model and I consider manyToOne and oneToOne relationships "eagerly" fetched and oneToMany "lazily" fetched.

I want to fetch Entity A and all its associations where a.id=?

- A oneToMany B

  - B oneToOne C

    - C  oneToMany D
  - B oneToOne E

    - E  oneToMany D
  - B oneToOne F

    - F  oneToMany D

Is it possible to load this entity in a single query?
Or in a subset of queries baring in mind the "n+1 selects problem"!

So far my solution to loading all of A associations was to perform the following:

"Select DISTINCT a from A a JOIN FETCH a.bs WHERE a.id=:aID"

And then iterate using code in order to fetch all other associations.

Collection B bs = A.getBs();

```
         for (final B b : bs) {
         b.getCs().getDs().size();
         b.getEs().getDs().size();
         b.getFs().getDs().size();
         }
```

Obviously there must be a better way of doing this.

Comment: To Dimitri, i have same problem. You have not accepted any answer. So which solution works for  you?

Comment: I solve most of use cases like these with [batch fetching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35039402/4754790).

Answer (score 8):

You might be interested in reading [this](http://blog.eyallupu.com/2010/06/hibernate-exception-simultaneously.html) article. I have tested both

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
```

and
 also using a Set instead of List, in combination with fetch = FetchType.EAGER it works.

Comment: using a `FetchType.EAGER` on a relation is generally an anti-pattern as not all relations need to be loaded, loading them without having to use them is a good example of performance issue in JPA-dependent applications.

What would be done usually is you load the data then initialize the data that you actually need independently via your JPQL query or via an `initialize` function.

Answer (score 3):

Use a FETCH JOIN. From the JPA 1.0 specification:

> #### 4.4.5.3 Fetch Joins
>
> A FETCH JOIN enables the fetching of an association
>   as a side effect of the execution of a
>   query. A FETCH JOIN is specified over
>   an entity and its related entities.
>
> The syntax for a fetch join is
>
> ```
> fetch_join ::= [ LEFT [OUTER] | INNER ] JOIN FETCH join_association_path_expression
> ```
>
> The association referenced by the
>   right side of the FETCH JOIN clause
>   must be an association that belongs to
>   an entity that is returned as a result
>   of the query. It is not permitted to
>   specify an identification variable for
>   the entities referenced by the right
>   side of the FETCH JOIN clause, and
>   hence references to the implicitly
>   fetched entities cannot appear
>   elsewhere in the query.
>
> The following query returns a set of
>   departments. As a side effect, the
>   associated employees for those
>   departments are also retrieved, even
>   though they are not part of the
>   explicit query result. The persistent
>   fields or properties of the employees
>   that are eagerly fetched are fully
>   initialized. The initialization of the
>   relationship properties of the
>   employees that are retrieved is
>   determined by the metadata for the
>   Employee entity class.
>
> ```
> SELECT d
> FROM Department d LEFT JOIN FETCH d.employees
> WHERE d.deptno = 1
> ```
>
> A fetch join has the same join
>   semantics as the corresponding inner
>   or outer join, except that the related
>   objects specified on the right-hand
>   side of the join operation are not
>   returned in the query result or
>   otherwise referenced in the query.
>   Hence, for example, if department 1
>   has five employees, the above query
>   returns five references to the
>   department 1 entity.

Of course, use it wisely, don't join too many tables or you will kill performances.

Comment: Yes, but in need too do
SELECT d
FROM Department d LEFT JOIN FETCH d.employees es LEFT JOIN FETCH es.employee.addresses
WHERE d.deptno = 1

And load all addresses each employee has.

Comment: @Dimitri: A FETCH JOIN is the way to fetch eagerly an association. I don't get your point (and I'm not sure you want a LEFT JOIN by the way).

Answer (score 1):

> *Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.*

How about JBoss ORM documentation?

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/chapters/fetching/Fetching.html

> > There are a number of scopes for defining fetching:
>
> *static* 
>  Static definition of fetching strategies is done in the
>   mappings. The statically-defined fetch strategies is used in the
>   absence of any dynamically defined strategies
>
> **SELECT** Performs a separate SQL select to load the data. This can
>   either be EAGER (the second select is issued immediately) or LAZY (the
>   second select is delayed until the data is needed). This is the
>   strategy generally termed N+1.
>
> **JOIN** Inherently an EAGER style of fetching. The data to be fetched is
>   obtained through the use of an SQL outer join.
>
> **BATCH** Performs a separate SQL select to load a number of related data
>   items using an IN-restriction as part of the SQL WHERE-clause based on
>   a batch size. Again, this can either be EAGER (the second select is
>   issued immediately) or LAZY (the second select is delayed until the
>   data is needed).
>
> **SUBSELECT** Performs a separate SQL select to load associated data based
>   on the SQL restriction used to load the owner. Again, this can either
>   be EAGER (the second select is issued immediately) or LAZY (the second
>   select is delayed until the data is needed).
>
> ---
>
> *dynamic (sometimes referred to as runtime)* 
>  
>  Dynamic definition is really use-case centric. There are multiple ways to define dynamic
>   fetching:
>
> **Fetch profiles** defined in mappings, but can be enabled/disabled on the
>   Session.
>
> **HQL/JPQL** and both Hibernate and JPA Criteria queries have the ability
>   to specify fetching, specific to said query.
>
> **Entity Graphs** Starting in Hibernate 4.2 (JPA 2.1) this is also an
>   option.

And to prove the answer above, here's an example:

> **FetchMode.SUBSELECT** To demonstrate how FetchMode.SUBSELECT works, we
>   are going to modify the FetchMode.SELECT mapping example to use
>   FetchMode.SUBSELECT:
>
> Example 17. FetchMode.SUBSELECT mapping example:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
```

> Now, we are going to fetch all Department entities that match a given
>   filtering criteria and then navigate their employees collections.
>
> Hibernate is going to avoid the N+1 query issue by generating a single
>   SQL statement to initialize all employees collections for all
>   Department entities that were previously fetched. Instead of using
>   passing all entity identifiers, Hibernate simply reruns the previous
>   query that fetched the Department entities.
>
> Example 18. FetchMode.SUBSELECT mapping example:

```
List<Department> departments = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select d " +
    "from Department d " +
    "where d.name like :token", Department.class)
    .setParameter( "token", "Department%" )
    .getResultList();

log.infof( "Fetched %d Departments", departments.size());

for (Department department : departments ) {
    assertEquals(3, department.getEmployees().size());
}
```

> -- Fetched 2 Departments

```
SELECT
    d.id as id1_0_
FROM
    Department d
where
    d.name like 'Department%'

-- Fetched 2 Departments

SELECT
    e.department_id as departme3_1_1_,
    e.id as id1_1_1_,
    e.id as id1_1_0_,
    e.department_id as departme3_1_0_,
    e.username as username2_1_0_
FROM
    Employee e
WHERE
    e.department_id in (
        SELECT
            fetchmodes0_.id
        FROM
            Department fetchmodes0_
        WHERE
            d.name like 'Department%'
    )
```