# Infinispan JPA 2nd level cache defaults

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, infinispan, second-level-cache

I'm trying to configure Infinispan as a hibernate 2nd level cache. Everything is fine, but I want to tweak the default configuration, i.e. the values that all caches shared.

Caches are automatically created for entities annotated with `@Cache`, and I can customize them one by one in `infinispan.xml` by `<distributed-cache-configuratoin>`. However, I'd like to have default values (e.g. eviction strategy) for all of these caches.

Another thing is, I want to mark all these generated caches as "distributed" (they are "local" by default).

Here's an exceprt from my `infinispan.xml`:

```
<cache-container default-cache="default" statistics="true">
    <transport stack="external-file" />
    <!-- Configuring specifics for the User entity. How to do it globally? -->
    <distributed-cache-configuration name="user" statistics="true" />
</cache-container>
```

How do I do these things?

Comment: The default cache config is named `entity`. Configure a cache having that name, and it should apply to all of the entities.

Comment: Nice.. thanks. do you have a reference from the documentation for that?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-provider-infinispan-config

Comment: Can you add that as an answer, so that I can accept it? (just maybe with version 8.0 rather than 5.1)

Comment: @Bozho The link points to Hibernate 5.1 which is the newest version currently.

Comment: @Bozho Please see my edited answer. Using a distributed Hibernate L2 cache may have a negative performance impact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [default cache configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-provider-infinispan-config) for entities is named `entity`:

> Cache configuration can differ for each type of data stored in the
>   cache. In order to override the cache configuration template, use
>   property `hibernate.cache.infinispan.data-type.cfg` where `data-type`
>   can be one of:
>
> `entity` Entities indexed by `@Id` or `@EmbeddedId` attribute.
>
> `immutable-entity` Entities tagged with `@Immutable` annotation or set
>   as `mutable=false` in mapping file.
>
> `naturalid` Entities indexed by their `@NaturalId` attribute.
>
> `collection` All collections.
>
> `timestamps` Mapping entity type → last modification timestamp. Used
>   for query caching.
>
> `query` Mapping query → query result.
>
> `pending-puts` Auxiliary caches for regions using invalidation mode
>   caches.

The default for `collection`, `immutable-entity` and `naturalid` is also the configuration specified for `entity`, so you don't have to configure them separately (if you don't want separate configurations of course), as can be seen in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/cache/infinispan/InfinispanRegionFactory.html#COLLECTION_CACHE_RESOURCE_PROP) and the [source code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.1.0/hibernate-infinispan/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cache/infinispan/InfinispanRegionFactory.java#L125).

**Note**

In general, making a Hibernate L2 cache distributed may not be a good idea, because entity instances are stored in [disassembled hydrated state](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-store-second-level-cache-entries/) in the L2 cache, meaning that only ids of the associated entities are stored together with the parent entity state.

Suppose you have the following entities (`A`, `B`, `C` are all cachable):

```
@Entity
public class A {
  @ManyToOne
  private B b;

  @OneToMany
  private Collection<C> cs;
}
```

Even if the `cs` collection were cachable also, to fully assemble an entity `A` instance from the cache you would have the following network round trips to the other nodes of the cluster:

1. Fetch the entity `A` state.
2. Fetch the entity `B` state based on id stored in the `b` association.
3. Fetch the collection of `cs` ids.
4. For each id in the `cs` collection, fetch the `C` entity state, one by one.

Obviously, if you are assembling of collection of `A` instances (from a result of a query for example), all of the above is executed for each instance of `A`.

This all implies that reading data from the database directly (with properly configured lazy loading, using [batch size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35039402/4754790) for example), could be much more efficient than all of the network round trips in a distributed cache.

Also, that's one of the reasons why the entity/collection cache should run in the invalidation cluster mode (data are cached only on the node that reads/writes it, but invalidated on other nodes when changed).