# Spring + Hibernate: How do I efficiently chain two link tables and include resulting data in single entity? (user-role-right)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, many-to-many, linktable

**Short version**

I have a basic setup where a user table is linked to a role table and a role table is linked to a right. These are both Many-to-Many relations. The roles are a dynamic entity and not of interest for the application (only for visual aspects). When I fetch a user I want to return the data in the user table including a list of the names of all rights.

To clarify, this is what I want the solution to do:

[image: solution overview]

I managed to get the rights in my user object and return them, but it's inefficient due to the extra query calls hibernate makes after the original query was called.

**Detailed version**

Let me first give you some information on how to entities are linked and what the code looks like. My (simplified) database table structure looks like this:

[image: Database diagram]

*User.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "user_id", columnDefinition = "user_id")
  private Long userId;

  @Transient
  private List<String> rights

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
    name = "user_role",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id"))
  @JsonIgnore
  private List<Role> roles;

  //Getters and setters
}
```

*Role.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "role_id", columnDefinition = "role_id")
  private Long roleId;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
    name = "user_role",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"))
  @JsonIgnore
  private List<Employee> employees;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
    name = "role_right",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "right_id", referencedColumnName = "right_id"))
  @JsonIgnore
  private List<Right> rights;


  //Getters and setters
}
```

*Right.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "right")
public class Right {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "right_id", columnDefinition = "right_id")
  private Long rightId;

  @Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "name")
  private String name;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
    name = "role_right",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "right_id", referencedColumnName = "right_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id"))
  @JsonIgnore
  private List<Role> roles;

  //Getters and setters
}
```

It's important to know that I use the Java Specifications API to join the tables:

```
return (root, query, cb) -> {
  query.distinct(true);
  Join rolesJoin = root.join("roles", JoinType.LEFT);
  Join rightsJoin = rolesJoin.join("rights", JoinType.LEFT);
  return cb.conjunction();
};
```

This creates the correct query:

```
select <columns go here> 
from employee user0_
left outer join user_role roles1_ on user0_.user_id=roles1_.user_id
left outer join role role2_ on roles1_.role_id=role2_.role_id
left outer join role_right rights3_ on role2_.role_id=rights3_.role_id
left outer join right right4_ on rights3_.right_id=right4_.right_id
```

Everything looked to good to me till now. But when I tried to fetch the names of all roles, there where more than two queries (count for page and the original one) being executed

```
//The original code uses lambda for this
for(Role role : user.getRoles()){
  for(Right right: role.getRights()){
    user.addRight(right.getName());
  }
}
```

The extra query looks like:

```
select <column stuff> 
from role_right rights0_
inner join right right1_ on rights0_.right_id=right1_.right_id
where rights0_.role_id=?
```

This makes the call very inefficient to me. In this case it's a single user, but with multiple users it adds up.

Is there a way to have a single query put the names of all rights in the user entity, without adding extra query executions?

Things I tried so far:

- Using `@SecondaryTable` to directly define column from the Right table in my User entity. I could not get to first link the Role to the User and then use fields from the Role table to link the Right table. So in the end I would have to @SecondaryTable annotation on top of my User object and define columns of the Right object below.
- Using `@Formula` in the User entity to insert a native call into the query. This did also not work as the annotation did not understand how to map everything into a list of rights.

There might be other options here, or I did something horribly wrong with implementing the ones above. But for now I don't which way to go in finding a solution for my problem. If someone could tell me, that would be great.

Thanks in advance,
Robin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `Root.join` which does just the joining of tables for the purposes of the query; lazy associations in the loaded entities will still not be initialized.

As I see, your intention is to initialize the lazy collections as well. For that you have to use [Root.fetch](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/FetchParent.html#fetch%28java.lang.String%29) (defined in the interface method inherited from the `FetchParent`):

> Create a fetch join to the specified collection-valued attribute using
>   the given join type.

However, your intention is not a good practice; do not join multiple collections in one query, otherwise the query result set will explode with full Cartesian product between the joined collections. Your result set contains `<num of users> * <num of roles per user> * <num of rights per role>` rows. So, each user data is repeated `<num of roles per user> * <num of rights per role>` times in the generated result set.

The approach I find to be the best and most straightforward is to specify [batch size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032559/batchsize-a-smart-or-stupid-use/35039402#35039402) on lazy associations.

Comment: @BatchSize is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I tried different approaches using the @BatchSize annotation. When fetching multiple entities it decreases the waiting time by quite a bit. Also the amount of queries being executed dropped to around 5 calls.

Comment: But when getting a single entity the fetch time was not affected by it. So sadly no improvement there. I wonder if there's a way to caches the queries that the @BatchSize annotations introduces, so that the speedup increases even more

Comment: @RobinHermans Take a look at the linked questions and answers (and further links there also). It is explained nicely, including the cached queries (loaders) used by the underlying batch size mechanism.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I'm gone try and optimize things a little bit better. The @BatchSize annotation already does good job on it (if you use it correctly that is).